# "RA layer request failed: REPORT request failed" during git-svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I've been trying to Git clone a Google Code SVN repository using the following command:

```
git svn clone --stdlayout https://wtorrent-project.googlecode.com/svn/ wtorrent-git
```

It gets as far as r11, then gives the following error message:

```
r11 = 6e04c0fb14aa3f6ab4d871eeed4a0526dc0e54d8 (refs/remotes/trunk)
RA layer request failed: REPORT request failed on '/svn/!svn/vcc/default': REPORT
of '/svn/!svn/vcc/default': 200 OK (https://wtorrent-project.googlecode.com) at
C:\Apps\msysgit/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 5653
```

This error message was generated by the latest msysgit (v1.7.8), but I get the same error message from my Gentoo box too.

Comment: For me, the most effective way to resolve this and other issues during migrating a huge project from SVN to Git (on Windows), was to perform the actual `git svn clone ...` thing _not_ on Windows but on Linux. I've quickly set up an **Ubuntu** 20 VMware machine and the whole migration process ran successfully without _any_ errors (and I had plenty of them on Windows before).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Revision 12 and hence 13, 14 are messed up ( someone added a branch trunk in branches, but later deleted it, and that confuses git-svn). You might want to do:

```
git svn clone -r 1:11 --stdlayout https://wtorrent-project.googlecode.com/svn/ wtorrent-git
cd wtorrent-git
git svn fetch -r 15:HEAD
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error message with a different project (after 50000 revisions). For me it helped to tidy up the git repository and then continue fetching from svn:

```
$ git gc
$ git svn fetch
```

Comment: It didn't help for me. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I fixed it by switching from cloning from secure HTTP (from SourceForge) to regular HTTP. So instead of cloning https://... I cloned http://. No problems after that.

Comment: nope, i get the error with `http` protocol

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to migrate svn to Git, try [SubGit](https://subgit.com/), free [download](https://subgit.com/download), and [documentation](https://subgit.com/documentation/). SubGit is a Java implementation, that is useful for both 1-time migrations and for mirroring svn to Git repositories and *v.v.* SubGit worked for me when `git-svn` didn't. SubGit works on *any* platform with the Java JRE. (FYI: If you have the Java JDK, and have set `JAVA_HOME` make sure the path is correct.). After downloading SubGit, extract the zip file, and enter the bin folder. Then follow the online documentation. A batch file for Windows and a shell file for Mac and Linux are both in the extracted `bin` folder. For Windows just replace `subgit` with `subgit.bat` in the following example:

```
$ subgit import --svn-url path://to/your/svn/repo GIT_REPO_PATH
```

This will create a new Git repo at `GIT_REPO_PATH` from the subversion repo given by the URL. See the documentation for other options such as specifying how you want to map `trunk/branches/tags/shelves` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem on an SVN repo with about 20K files. It happened when fetching a revision where about 2000 files had been moved in SVN.  `git svn fetch` failed on Windows but succeeded on a Mac.  Another colleague was able to update fine on Windows.

I thought it could be significant that I was connected via a VPN, so I copied the git repo to a machine in the office and ran fetch from there - it worked!  So I think this could be some kind of timeout issue when transferring a very large revision, since git-svn uses a number of Perl scripts that are provided by the msysgit subsystem, and those operations are slower than on a native Unix/Linux-based system.