# RA layer request failed? what git-svn did to the repo?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

not the same as this [RA layer request failed while git-svn fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750120/ra-layer-request-failed-while-git-svn-fetch), no network issues

a bit similar with this ["RA layer request failed: REPORT request failed" during git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451480/ra-layer-request-failed-report-request-failed-during-git-svn), but i am not using git-svn in cygwin

the error message is as follows:

```
RA layer request failed: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to REPORT request for '/repos/asf/!svn/vcc/default' at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 5669
```

it's 403 error:(

what happened?

There is no directory named !svn in fact (by clicking http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/!svn you may know this directory does not exists, so how did git-svn generate such a absurd directory name),

so why git-svn want to find this directory?

The behavior of git-svn is confusing:( what it want to do to svn repo?

and why there is 403 error?

how to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, apache.org just bans people using git-svn for their large repository (usually in the middle of such clone). "!svn" is from DAV protocol implementation on that server. To avoid you can try to find any mirror for that location. If there's not any mirror, you can try to clone not the whole history but starting from some revision in order not fetch too many revisions (-r option).

Comment: And of course you can use Subversion to work with Subversion repository :) Personally I prefer this option.

Comment: how to specify the revision from where to start to clone?

Comment: -r REV1:REV2, for example, git svn clone -s -r 1376018:HEAD <URL> <target>